# Importing SRTM Data into Grass

Tags: grass-gis, import, srtm

I am having issues importing an SRTM HGT file into Grass. I first made a new location as the instructions from this [Grass Newsletter Tutorial](https://grass.osgeo.org/newsletter/GRASSNews_vol3.pdf) states. I then went to the [download site](https://web.archive.org/web/20200518181904/https://dds.cr.usgs.gov/srtm/version2_1/SRTM3/Eurasia/) and downloaded the file to my desktop. Inside GRASS, I went to

File > Import raster data > SRTM HGT import [r.in.srtm]

I choose the filename of the .hgt.zip file and remove the extension .hgt.zip (as the instructions say).

The statement looks like this:

```
r.in.srtm input=C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\N47E007
```

The following is the output that I'm getting:

```
Extracting 'C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\N47E007'...
Converting input file to BIL...
mv: cannot stat `C:\\Users\\Joe\\Desktop\\N47E007.hgt': No
such file or directory
ERROR 4: `C:\Users\Joe\Desktop\N47E007.bil' does not exist
in the file system,
and is not recognised as a supported dataset name.
rmdir: C:\Users\Joe\Documents\grassdata/demolocation/PERMANE
NT/.tmp/8120.0: Directory not empty
ERROR: Unable to import data
```

At the beginning of the script, the file is definitely there because the program recognizes it and starts converting it. Once it produces an error, I notice the file has been moved to another directory

```
C:\Users\Joe\Documents\grassdata\demolocation\PERMANENT\.tmp\8120.0
```

What can I do to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: You use an  "old" tutorial, simply look at the new [GRASS GIS: HOWTO import SRTM elevation data](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/HOWTO_import_SRTM_elevation_data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unzip the zip file, not rename it. Then it will work.

As per gene's suggestion, see also the GRASS Wiki article: [GRASS GIS: HOWTO import SRTM elevation data](http://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/HOWTO_import_SRTM_elevation_data).